# How to change xpath according to variable defined

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Hope you are doing well.

There is a site which the xpath name of the dropdown box will change everyday (i.e. the dropdown box named "2020-10-26timeWindows" today and will change to "2020-10-27timeWindows" tomorrow).

I can use datetime to dynamic change the dropdown name. However, I need to select value from dropdown box as well. Very much appreciate it if you could help to look into the following code and tell is there anyway to use "today" into dropdown.find_element_by_xpath?

```
today = str(datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.ID,  "{}timeWindows".format(today))
time.sleep(0.2)       
dropdown.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id=\'2020-10-26timeWindows\']/option[. = '19:30 – 19:45']").click()
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I will use format strings like this:

```
today = str(datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
t = "{}timeWindows".format(today)
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.ID, t)
time.sleep(0.2)       
dropdown.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id=\'{}\']/option[. = '19:30 – 19:45']".format(t)).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

- you can make it dynamic using this edit

```
today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
```

- edit in your code

```
today = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.ID,  "{}timeWindows".format(today))
time.sleep(0.2)       
dropdown.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id=\'2020-10-26timeWindows\']/option[. = '19:30 – 19:45']").click()
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) for more help